# IntelliJ Run Config for Tomcat - preconfigure Application Context

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

When I want to deploy a java web project with a non-ROOT context path, I can configure that.

The manual way:

- In Eclipse:

  - via project properties

    - go to Web Project Settings
    - configure it right there
  - via the Servers view

    - double click the server
    - go to modules
    - edit it there
- In IntelliJ's Tomcat Server run config

  - Deployment tab
  - add the artifact you want
  - edit the Application context

In the times of maven etc, this should be automated, so not every time a web application is deployed/undeployed I have to edit this again.
Or whenever a new developer joins the project.

Now for Eclipse you can set a property in your pom, telling it which path to use:

```
<properties>
    <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/my/custom/context/path</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
</properties>
```

---

Is there an equivalent for IntelliJ?

---

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA integrates well with Maven, in which case just follow the [official Apache Tomcat recommendation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/html-manager-howto.html#Deploy_using_a_Context_configuration_%22.xml%22_file) and you'll solve the problem.

`/META-INF/context.xml` is a Tomcat-specific config file. It is used to configure how your app is deployed to Tomcat, including, among other things, the context path at which it exists.

```
<Context docBase="yourAppName" path="/yourAppPath" reloadable="true">
```